# Unable to delete entries in host files

Tags: windows-10, drivers, dns, hosts-file

I added too many hosts file entries such that now my whole computer lags and freezes, my Chrome cannot load any websites, and my computer says that my Wi-Fi has no internet although other devices connected to it work just fine.

I tried to delete the file by following [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default-c2a43f9d-e176-c6f3-e4ef-3500277a6dae), but it says that the file is being used by the DNS client and cannot be altered at the moment. I also tried disabling the DNS client but windows outright denies it from happening.

I can alter it in Notepad but cannot save as it says the DNS client is using it. How do I fix this? (I'm using Windows 10.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into safe mode, delete the existing `hosts` file, and replace it with the default content

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Comment: It works. Thanks so much! 